# jQGrid groupText

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

How do you access other data besides {0} for the grouping column and {2} for the number of rows. I would expect I could access the JSON through a function() {} or something ... any ideas even if it is a little hacky?

```
...
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
           groupField:['GroupByThisField'],
           groupText: ['My Group {0} = {1}']

}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am trying to do the exact same thing using the struts2-jquery-plugin owned by johgep.
i was wondering if having a custom formatter on the grouping column would work.

I Did try it yesterday but it didn't work. I raised a request to johgep for the same.
Will let you know in case of any updates.

Comment: Thanks @"Darshan Shroff" I think thats a good idea. We need access to the whole array that forms the group and a custom formatter would work nicely.

Comment: Johannes (struts2-jquery-plugin owner) mentioned that this is a jqGrid issue. i raised an issue over there, but there seem to be no updates since                                             https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/100

Comment: This is answered here. And works like a charm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803081/jqgrid-grouping-grouptext-formatting-and-modification